# Read XML file in Dart

Tags: xml, dart

I'm new in Dart language.

I'm wanting to read a XML file and I'm following these links (they are practical the same) https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/xml or the github's page https://github.com/renggli/dart-xml.

But I'm having problems with some methods like "findAllElements". I'm importing in my dart file the xml library that they have and importing the collection, core and html:

```
library xml;    
import 'dart:collection';
import 'dart:core';
import 'dart:html';
```

My code is:

```
  var document = responseText;

  var titles = document.findAllElements('trkpt');

  titles
      .map((node) => node.text)
      .forEach(print);
```

While I test my program I have this error:

> NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'findAllElements'

What do I need to import more? I'm still exploring this language and my goal is just get data from XML and apply a filter for it! Any tutorial? Any suggestion?

Comment: Your document variable is evidently not a XmlDocument instance. What is responseText? If it s a string containing xml you need to parse it to get an XmlDocument: var document = parse(responseText);

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I see two problems, but I might be missing parts of your code:

- You don't specify what `responseText` is, but it looks to me like a `String`. As explained in the tutorial you linked, you need to parse the text before you can perform queries on it.
- You don't import the XML library, please follow the install instructions on https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/xml.

The following minimal example works for me:

```
library example;

import 'package:xml/xml.dart' as xml;

void main() {
  var storeXml = '<?xml?><store><book title="First"/><book title="Second"/></store>';
  var storeDocument = xml.parse(storeXml);
  print(storeDocument.findAllElements('book'));
}
```

Comment: I think to start I need to learn to import packages, my problems are these little tricks. How do I do to get that package in my package folder? Or better, where can I get them?

Comment: Do step by step what it says in the "Installing" tab on https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/xml. Also this might be helpful with the general concepts: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/get-started.html

Comment: Thank you man! It worked! Now I have a little problem I would be thankful for your answer: how do you get an attribute from every node?

For example, from the example in the link, imagine that I want to get the language in every node?

Comment: `storeDocument.findAllElements('book').map((each) => each.getAttribute('title')` extracts the titles.