# how do i read xml file value

Tags: flutter, dart

this is my XML data file:

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<contact-info>
   <name>Tanmay Patil</name>
   <company>TutorialsPoint</company>
   <phone>(011) 123-4567</phone>
</contact-info>
```

and this is my flutter code:

```
  Future _xml() async {

              http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
              XmlData = XmlDocument.parse(response.body);
              final wantData = XmlData!.findAllElements('contact-info');

  }
```

please how i can get the value TutorialsPoint from my xml file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read XML file in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35880409/read-xml-file-in-dart)

Comment: ``final company = XmlData.findAllElements('company').single.text;`` will give you ``TutorialsPoint``

Comment: thank you but
if i have this XML:
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<info>
   <name>Tanmay Patil</name>
   <company>TutorialsPoint</company>
   <phone>(011) 123-4567</phone>
   <contact>
    <name>fabian Patil</name>
    <company>gmailPoint</company>
    <phone>(011) 0532-4567</phone>
    </contact>
    <contact>
    <name>daniel Patil</name>
    <company>gmailPoint</company>
    <phone>(011) 0665-4567</phone>
    </contact>
</info>
and i want get the second informations of contact, the (011) 0665-456 phone number for exemple, how i can do that please ?

Comment: find it print(wantData.map((e) => e.getElement('phone')).elementAt(0));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [xml](https://pub.dev/packages/xml) package

```
import 'package:xml/xml.dart' as xml;
var xmldata='<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<contact-info>
   <name>Tanmay Patil</name>
   <company>TutorialsPoint</company>
   <phone>(011) 123-4567</phone>
</contact-info>';







void main() {
 
  var contact = xml.parse(xmldata);
  print(contact.findAllElements('phone'));
}
```

Comment: pleas up the answer if it solved your issue

Comment: FYI, he is already using the XML package.